# Database updates not readable while PHPunit WebTestCase (Symfony 5.1)

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, symfony5

I have a problem asserting updates made by a form are really written in the database.

I explain, I first do a create test (testCreateLactationForm), very similar to the edit test. In that firs test y check the record is finally inserted and all works fine:

```
        $finalRecords = $qb->where($qb->expr()->like('p.comments', ':comments'))
            ->setParameter('comments', '%'.$payload["form[comments]"].'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        $this->assertTrue(count($finalRecords) == (count($initialRecords) + 1));
```

After that, I made a dependant test where I locate las record, navigate to edit form, and update the modality and comments fields. In last line, when asserting Modality is equal to ONE_HOUR_REDUCTION, entity modality field remains with original creation value, so it fails, while in database the value was succesfully updated.

```
class HhrrProceduresControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
    private $entityManager;
    private $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->client = self::createClient();
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $this->entityManager = $kernel
            ->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();

        $this->hrmLogger = $kernel
            ->getContainer()
            ->get('monolog.logger.hrm');

    }

    [...]

    /**
     * @depends testCreateLactationForm
     */
    public function testEditLactationProcedure()
    {
        $payload = [
            "hhrr_procedure_lactation[modality]" => HhrrProcedureLactationModality::ONE_HOUR_REDUCTION,
            "hhrr_procedure_lactation[iniDate]" => "07/02/2022",
            "hhrr_procedure_lactation[endDate]" => "13/02/2022",
            "hhrr_procedure_lactation[hhrrProcedure][comments]" => "XXX--TEST--XXX | UPDATED",
        ];

        $qb = $this->entityManager->getRepository(HhrrProcedure::class)->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $initialRecord = $qb->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        $this->client->followRedirects(true);
        $this->client->request('GET', '/rrhh/tramites/'.$initialRecord[0]->getId().'/editar-tramite/', [], [], ['HTTP_X-AUTH-USERNAME' => $this->logged_in_user]);
        $crawler = $this->client->submitForm('Siguiente', $payload);

        $this->writeOutput(__FUNCTION__, $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());

        // verificar retorno correcto de la página
        $this->assertSame(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

        /** @var HhrrProcedure $updatedRecord */
        $updatedRecord = $this->entityManager->getRepository(HhrrProcedure::class)->find($initialRecord[0]->getId());
        /** FAILS --> **/ $this->assertEquals($updatedRecord->getHhrrProcedureLactation()->getModality(),HhrrProcedureLactationModality::ONE_HOUR_REDUCTION);
    }
```

In addition to that, if I try to write aditional dependant test, assertion is ok...

```
    /**
     * @depends testEditLactationProcedure
     */
    public function testEditLactationProcedureAssertion()
    {
        $qb = $this->entityManager->getRepository(HhrrProcedure::class)->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $initialRecord = $qb->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        $this->assertEquals($initialRecord[0]->getHhrrProcedureLactation()->getModality(),HhrrProcedureLactationModality::ONE_HOUR_REDUCTION);

    }
```

Some help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine entities are persisted in an internal cache (which is not the case when you use `findBy` methods, that load a new documents). You need to use
`EntityManagerInterface`'s `refresh($entityObject)` or `clear()` in order to get fresh data from the database.